# Using annotated field to order_by in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I have a queryset that has an annotated value that uses conditional expressions in it:

```py
def with_due_date(self: _QS):
        self.annotate(
            due_date=models.Case(
                *[
                    models.When(
                        FKMODEL__field=field,
                        then=models.F('created_at') - timedelta(days=days)
                    )
                    for field, days in due_date_mapping.items()
                ],
                output_field=models.DateTimeField(),
            ),
        )
        return self
```

Once trying to apply order_by on this queryset by the annotated value I get an error that the field cannot be resolved

```
File "/code/api/nodes.py", line 2577, in add_order_by
    return qs.order_by(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1295, in order_by
    obj.query.add_ordering(*field_names)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 2167, in add_ordering
    self.names_to_path(item.split(LOOKUP_SEP), self.model._meta)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1677, in names_to_path
    raise FieldError(
graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: Cannot resolve keyword 'due_date' into field. Choices are:
```

How come I cannot order by the annotated field value here?

Answer (score 0):

`QuerySet`'s are *immutable*, so you return the newly created one:

```
def with_due_date(self: _QS):
    return self.annotate(
        due_date=models.Case(
            *[
                models.When(
                    FKMODEL__field=field,
                    then=models.F('created_at') - timedelta(days=days),
                )
                for field, days in due_date_mapping.items()
            ],
            output_field=models.DateTimeField(),
        ),
    )
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't quite catch it. Im am using the new queryset before by adding .with_due_date() to the queryset

Comment: oh ur instantly returning it , right

Comment: @Robertas: `self.annotate` does *not* modify the queryset, it creates a modified copy.

Comment: After changing it now i can see another issue:

```python
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 302, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1507, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 95, in __iter__
    setattr(obj, attr_name, row[col_pos])
graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: can't set attribute 'due_date'
```